# Hide WSTP application from taskbar

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, c++

I just updated a small `MathLink` program that I made a while ago, and recompiled it using the new `WSTP` system (Mathematica 11.2).

The new version runs fine, but now this external `WSTP` program is shown in the taskbar (on Windows 10) once it's called via `Install[]`, which was not the case with the old version that I created a while ago with the old `MathLink` system. On one of my computers, a (frozen) console window is shown when I click on the taskbar item, but on another system nothing happens when I click on that taskbar item...

Interestingly, this even happens for the pre-compiled `WSTP` programs supplied with Mathematica (for example the `addtwo` program described on the `Install[]` help page).

I build my program using VS 2017 using the instructions in the [Mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPDeveloperGuide-Windows.html). I already tried [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139637/hide-console-of-windows-application) to force the linker to use the "Windows" type instead of "Console", but it didn't change anything...

Any ideas on how one can get rid of these `WSTP` programs showing up in the taskbar?

Comment: If you follow the structure of the examples that come with Mathematica, the button will appear in the taskbar. This has *always* been the case.  It has nothing to do with MathLink/WSTP updates. Perhaps try comparing your old program with the new one and see where the difference is.  I would suspect the MLInitializeIcon part, but I am not very familiar with Windows anymore.  If you want to compile in console mode, you'd use the `main()` function instead of `WinMain`, but then you'd get a console window, even worse than a taskbar button.

Comment: Ok - didn't know that this was always the case for the standard programs! My old program used the `main()` function, but there was no console window... If I use the `main()` function in my updated version, I get a console window... so not sure where the problem is... I compiled the old version with MinGW though, so maybe using VS is the "problem"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was really simple and Szabolcs was right - removing the line

```
if (!WSInitializeIcon(hinstCurrent, nCmdShow)) return 1;
```

from the `WinMain` function in the standard `WSTP` C/C++ source file works, and no taskbar item is shown.

(Not sure why my old version, which used the `main()` function and was compiled with MinGW, didn't generate a console window or taskbar item though).